# In a TreeMap and a TreeSet, is it okay for compareTo() and equals() be based off of two different fields?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset, treemap, treeset

In a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and a [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), is it okay for `compareTo()` and `equals()` be based off of two different fields?

Since both are binary search trees, go left and go right is based on key.Compare(). So theoretically I could do the sorting based on one field (which I will use in `compareTo()` ) but I could use a separate field for `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Is there any harm in doing this? In my understanding, If I use this same object in a HashMap or a HashSet, As long as equals() and hashCode() are based off of the same field, there should not be any issue.